# Docker Hub - Automated Build failed, but local build on my raspberry runs without problems

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dockerhub

I have an automated docker build at docker hub that fails while it runs without errors locally (on my raspberry4)

The logs are [here](https://hub.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/jiwidi/jupyter-lab-rpi/builds/ff0d486b-ad8b-4e3b-aee6-2e547484e244), text here:

```
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'18.03.1-ee-3', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.37', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'b9a5c95', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.10.2'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.37
Platform: {u'Name': u''}
Version: 18.03.1-ee-3
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: b9a5c95
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.10.2
Starting build of index.docker.io/jiwidi/jupyter-lab-rpi:latest...
Step 1/22 : FROM resin/raspberrypi3-python:3.6
---> 97f0dfa04606
Step 2/22 : MAINTAINER 
---> Running in e83c3b081120
Removing intermediate container e83c3b081120
---> 231f400a33d1
Step 3/22 : WORKDIR /root
Removing intermediate container 94b752c9953c
---> adc8cb2817d2
Step 4/22 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev libzmq-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev
---> Running in ded49f1ec6dd
[91mstandard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
[0m
Removing intermediate container ded49f1ec6dd
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev libzmq-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The line where it fails doesnt provide much feedback:

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 1`

I have it linked with my GitHub repository where you can find the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jiwidi/jupyter-lab-docker-rpi/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Could this be because my image is building in ARM architecture and docker-hub runs x86?

Answer (score 0):

Hi logs link not working, have you tried separating commands?

something like this to know what is failing?

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzmq-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev
```

Comment: Hey! just tried and it fails at `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: have you tried replace deprecated image resin/raspberrypi3-python:3.6?

Comment: I just tried with a newer image (from just a few days) and still happening the same error, it fails at sudo apt-get update. It still runs good locally. New dockerfile : https://github.com/jiwidi/jupyter-lab-docker-rpi/blob/46050f6a5c17cb18eb98ec45c08b49487b859280/Dockerfile

Comment: builds fine on macos catalina 10.15.3

Comment: yes it runs okay locally but fails on the docker-hub auto building I have set up by linking my image to the github repository. I can not understand why